# Docker registry garbage collector does not delete layers

Tags: docker

So I have private docker registry and all I want to do is to be able to delete manifests and dangling layers. 
What I am doing is finding digest of the manifest in Registry API, then sending DELETE on /v2/NAME/manifests/SHA256 which is working perfectly fine. Then I run garbage collector by docker exec -it CONTAINERID bin/registry garbage-collect -m /etc/docker/registry/config.yml 
GC finds some loose blobs deletes them.

It looks good but when I push the same image again to registry it says layers already exists, and I can't pull this image from registry.
When I try to GET manifest from API, tag is on the tags list but GET /v2/NAME/manifests/TAG returns 404

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
 registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true"
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/registry:/var/lib/registry
```

and config.yaml

```
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
  addr: :5000
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
health:
  storagedriver:
    enabled: true
    interval: 10s
    threshold: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer maybe its not the best solution but it works.
Problem is storage.cache that holds layers. When I removed this sections from config.yaml everything worked as it should. If you need cache then you should find way to clear layers from cache after GC.